# Xml format show attributes in the new line (Python)

Tags: python, xml

I am trying break attributes of an XML node into separate lines. The input is a string like:

```
<computer color="read" brand="Dell" version="T430" description="2013 new style" />
```

I split the string with , a space, but since there are some spaces in the description, it didn't work out. I use Python to generate the XML code.

Can anyone explain to me how to do this?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use a XML parser for this, and get the values by key, i.e. `version="T430"` etc?

Comment: the input was taken as the whole xml file, so it is not easy to use XML parser, it is not an object, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your XML code is well-formed, the quotation marks can only occur there as delimiters of attribute values. Hence, you can first chop the string by quotes and then reconnect them by alternating separators: every odd one will be a quote and every even one will be a quote and a newline.

For instance, this code would work, if `a` contains your input string:

```
'"'.join(map(lambda x:'\n'+x if x.startswith(' ') else x, a.split('"')))
```

(it also uses the fact that you need newlines where a quote is followed by an extra space).
Or, if you dislike lambda-functions for some reason ;)

```
'"'.join(['\n'+x if x.startswith(' ') else x for x in a.split('"')])
```